# How can I assign an IMTLTexture to SCNMaterialProperty's contents in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, scenekit, metalkit

I have a Metal texture that I've created with:

`IMTLTexture texture = device.CreateTexture(textureDescriptor);`

And I have an SCNNode's and I want to assign the Metal texture to its diffuse contents:

`SCNNode node = new SCNNode(); // assign geometry, etc`

And now I want to do something like this:

`node.Geometry.FirstMaterial.Diffuse.Contents = (NSObject)texture;`

But I get a runtime invalid cast error.

Assigning Metal textures to SCNMaterialProperty's contents works in Swift (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents), but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Xamarin.

Anyone know how I can do this?